# NSMutableArray dynamic update?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a code like below.

```
Ticket *ticket1 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"INC1234" group:@"PIMS-EU-COG" type:@"Incident" status:@"Active" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Dinesh" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];
Ticket *ticket2 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"PRJ2342" group:@"PIMS-EU-COG" type:@"Project" status:@"Closed" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Dinesh" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];
Ticket *ticket3 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"ENC1234" group:@"PIMS-EU-COG" type:@"Enhancement" status:@"Awaiting vendor" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Dinesh" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];
Ticket *ticket4 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"INC2345" group:@"CRM-EU-COG" type:@"Incident" status:@"Active" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Alex" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];
Ticket *ticket5 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"PRJ2345" group:@"CRM-EU-COG" type:@"Project" status:@"Pending" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Alex" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];
Ticket *ticket6 = [[Ticket alloc] initWithName:@"ENC2345"group:@"CRM-EU-COG" type:@"Enhancement" status:@"Active" createdOn:@"20-Oct-2013" createdBy:@"Alex" completionDate:@"23-Oct-2013" notes:@"1. All works coreectly 2. New variables are created.."];

self.TicketsFinal= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:ticket1,ticket2,ticket3, nil];
/*
if (groupFinal == @"PIMS-EU-COG") {

    self.TicketsFinal= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:ticket1,ticket2,ticket3, nil];
}else if (groupFinal == @"CRM-EU-COG")
{
    self.TicketsFinal= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:ticket4,ticket5,ticket6,ticket7,ticket8,ticket9, nil];
}*/
```

I have 3 parameters:

1. GroupFinal
2. TypeFinal
3. StatusFinal.

`groupsFinal` will hold the group (ex:PIMS-EU-COG) details. `typeFinal` will hold what type of ticket (ex: Incident) and statusFinal will hold status of the ticket (ex: Active). These 3 parameters are obtained from previous view.

I have a array called as self.ticketsFinal which should hold tickets based on selected criteria alone. I tried hardcoding the group (last commented part) and navigating, which is not the correct way.

Ex: When `groupFinal`, `TypeFinal`, `statusFinal` have values as `PIMS-EU-COG`, `Incident`, `Active`, then in this case the self.TiketsFinal should hold only `Ticket1` (which meets the criteria).

When an `All` is selected in `typeFinal` and `statusFinal` all the tickets in the group should be updated in array.

Can anyone please help. You help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use NSPredicate for this purpose:

```
[self.TicketsFinal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group = %@", @"PIMS-EU-COG"]];
```

This would return a new array containing only the objects for which the group is equal to 'PIMS-EU-COG'.

You can see a guide to using NSPredicate [here](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

Also, if you're using this method, your array doesn't need to be mutable. If you really want to **discard** the items that don't match, you can do

```
[self.TicketsFinal filterUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group = %@", @"PIMS-EU-COG"]];
```

In your case, you have multiple parameters that you want to use to filter down the set of objects. You can use `NSCompoundPredicate` for this:

```
NSPredicate *groupPredicate = [NSPredicate 
     predicateWithFormat:@"group = %@", @"PIMS-EU-COG"];

NSPredicate *typePredicate = [NSPredicate 
     predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @"Incident"];

NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate 
     andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[groupPredicate, typePredicate]];

NSArray *result = [self.TicketsFinal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

Comment: Hi Mat..Thanks for you reply. It is very good stuff to learn. But my requirement little different. I have the tickets as NSObjects. How can i dynamically assign the object to the Array. i tried the code you provided but it returns empty value.

Comment: Sorry Mat..Got it right now. !! Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.!